# Should I include self-studied courses/topics in undergraduate resume?

Tags: cv, undergraduate

I'm preparing my resume for internship application.

I have already included courses that I emphasized more on (reading extra advanced material outside of the course's material scope).

I read lots of books. Should I include topics that I self-studied to my resume as extracurricular knowledge?

Comment: For what its worth: my reading habits when looking at CVs are such that I mostly care about the stuff that is verifiable (at least in principle) like course grades, transcripts and the like, and very little about things that the author just claims without any evidence. It is probably not harmful to include these things but at least for me that would make little difference.

Comment: What kind of interships and will this knowledge be helpful for the internship?  (E.g., statistics and data analysis are very marketable skills.)

Comment: @Kimball some related directly, some not.

Comment: In that case I would say at least put the useful skills in your CV and you may get asked more about it at the interview stage.  Just make sure it's not framed in such a way that makes it look like you're, say, an expert in regression analysis when you only know how to do simple linear regression.  Then this would be a disappointment if it comes up in an interview, rather than "oh good, he knows a little bit about regression."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am sure that there is a very wide range of opinion/reaction to what some people call "self-study". For me (grad admissions in mathematics in the U.S.), evidence of interest in reading things beyond what coursework demands is an extremely positive and unusual indicator. That is, so far as people seem to let on, no one reads any math book that's not a textbook for a course they've registered for, does not read ahead, and so on. I don't understand it, although I've seen it for decades.

Yes, it is not as easy to "document" reading things as it is to document "grades in courses"... but my own opinion is that even excellent grades in courses form only a limited positive, since it refers to compliance, obedience, etc., even if at a challending level/rate/whatever.

That is, for me, mathematics is not merely a school subject, nor merely a thing that one might get research funding for... :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When you mean "evidence", I guess the only evidence that is either recommendation letters from my prof's or copies of textbooks in my personal library? haha. I agree that excellent grades often refer to obedience and compliance.

Comment: By the way, that's what my professor told me when I asked for additonal references to read when he refered to Neural Nets in class (Math student). It seemed to him "remarkable and unusual".

Comment: "evidence" can also include public repositories, for my degree private but shareable github repositories or stackoverflow can be used or, for math, mathoverflow or proofs/lessons/etc on blogs - particular if they reference the book read and show the work (thinking process)

Answer (score 1):

Although certified studies would be given a higher weight, it should be fine to add your self-taught knowledge in a résumé as long as you are able to back it up with any related work or your speech during an interview.